# jquery + codeigniter + knockout + sammy, cannot retrieve post data

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, knockout.js, sammy.js

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0rc2, with jQuery 1.11.3, Knockout.js 3.3.0 and Sammy.js.
I'm trying to do a post call and retrieve some JSON data to put in my viewModel.

My view is:

```
<!-- Mails grid -->
<table class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: mails">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToMail">
            <td data-bind="text: from"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: to"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: subject"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My ViewModel is:

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
    self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
    self.chosenMailData = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours
    self.goToFolder = function (folder) {
        location.hash = folder
    };
    self.goToMail = function (mail) {
        location.hash = mail.folder + '/' + mail.id
    };

    // Client-side routes    
    Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#:folder', function () {
            self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
            self.chosenMailData(null);
            $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/app/getmail'; ?>", {
                folder: this.params.folder
            }, self.chosenFolderData)
        });

        this.get('#:folder/:mailId', function () {
            self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
            self.chosenFolderData(null);
            $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/app/getmail'; ?>", {
                mailId: this.params.mailId
            }, self.chosenMailData);
        });

        this.get('', function () {
            this.app.runRoute('get', '#Inbox')
        });
    }).run();
};
```

At this line of viewModel:

```
        $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/app/getmail'; ?>", { folder : this.params.folder }, self.chosenFolderData)
```

I know that the app/getmail send me the correct data. I tested with:

```
        $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/app/getmail'; ?>", { folder : this.params.folder }, function(data) { console.log(data) } )
```

And I can see the data retrieved at console.
If I replace the $.post with the data directly to self.chosenFolderData, like that:

```
self.chosenFolderData( { "id" : "Inbox", "mails" : [{"id" : 1, "folder" : "Inbox" ... }] );
```

It worked well.
But as the code is, I get this return:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return mails }"
Message: mails is not defined
```

I realize that data is not assigned to self.chosenFolderData.
I even tried something like that:

```
        $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/app/getmail'; ?>", { folder : this.params.folder }, function(data) { console.log(data); self.chosenFolderData(data); } )
```

But it not works. I can see data at console, but have the same error.

By the way, this is based on Knockoutjs.com Tutorial here: [Webmail](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You have no `mails` member of your viewmodel, so the `foreach` binding is failing.

Comment: `mails` is an item of JSON data returned from `$.post` call. It seems a scope problem, but I don't know how to solve it. If I assign a data after `$.post` call, It work,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I need to put `'json'` at the end of `$.post` call, like this:

```
    $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/app/getmail'; ?>", { folder : this.params.folder }, self.chosenFolderData, 'json');
```